# Specify which form to do post call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I currently do one post call with html form fields. How do I specify which values to do a post call with? For instance, I want to do 2 separate post ajax call with username/password and username/email.

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: $('form').attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      alert("Login successful. Redirecting");
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = "3.3.3.3/login"
      }, 5000);

    },
    error: function(data, status, xhr) {
      $('form').trigger("reset");
      alert("Failed to login. Please try again.");
    }
  });

  return false;
  alert("AJAX request successfully completed");
});
<html>
```

html

```
<head>
  <title>Log In</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="1.1.1.1/login" method="POST">

    <div class="login">
      <div class="login-screen">
        <div class="app-title">
          <h1> Login</h1>
        </div>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="username" placeholder="Username">
        <input class="form-control" type="password" required name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input class="form-control" type="hidden" required name="eauth" value="pam">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" required name="email" placeholder="email">

        <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Log In" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Or have 2 different forms or in the `submit` event, check which fields have values (condition) and have 2 different ajax calls.

Comment: How do you have two different forms and do a post with my current code? Can you give sample example?

Comment: Consider the second approach, it would fit your current code.

Comment: How do you specify which form to submit it with if I make 2 different forms? I think that'd be better.

Comment: Ok, so if you have 2 forms, just add an `id` attribute, like: `<form id="form1" ...>` and change your jquery code to `$('form#form1`).submit(`

Comment: If I have two forms, wouldn't they all appear as html though? That's problematic. I need to submit once by clicking submit with two forms.